# Get the ranking of the TOTAL values from PHP that is not stored in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

Good Day, I am working on some scoring system that would display all the scores by all of the users and would sum it up using `PHP` from `MySQL`. The result is working fine and the computation as well (the computation is done with `php`, not on `MySQL`). Now my problem is, how can I rank the total scores from highest to lowest.

Here's the code:

```
$sel_query="Select * from tbl_scores";
$result = mysql_query($sel_query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$crit_3 = $row["crit_3"];
$crit_3a = number_format($crit_3);

$crit2_3 = $row["crit2_3"];
$crit2_3a = number_format($crit2_3);

$crit3_3 = $row["crit3_3"];
$crit3_3a = number_format($crit3_3);

$user1 = ($crit_3) ;
$user2 = ($crit2_3);
$user3 = ($crit3_3);
$divide = ($user1 + $user2 + $user3); 
$total = number_format($divide / 9  , 2, '.', '');
$average = number_format($total * 0.15 , 2, '.', '');
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1.Please stop using (deprecated+removed) `mysql_*`,use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`.2.Define an array variable outside of the loop, and inside in the loop assign total scores to that array.3. Now you will get an array of scores and now you can use short methods to get data correctly.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Please stop using (deprecated from php5.5 +removed from php7) `mysql_*`,use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`.

2.Define an array variable outside of the loop, and inside in the loop assign total scores to that array.

3.Now you will get an array of scores and now you can use `rshort()` method to get data correctly.

So the code should be like below:-

```
$sel_query="Select * from tbl_scores";
$result = mysql_query($sel_query);
$scores_array = array();//create an array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$crit_3 = $row["crit_3"];
$crit_3a = number_format($crit_3);

$crit2_3 = $row["crit2_3"];
$crit2_3a = number_format($crit2_3);

$crit3_3 = $row["crit3_3"];
$crit3_3a = number_format($crit3_3);

$user1 = ($crit_3) ;
$user2 = ($crit2_3);
$user3 = ($crit3_3);
$divide = ($user1 + $user2 + $user3); 
$total = number_format($divide / 9  , 2, '.', '');
$average = number_format($total * 0.15 , 2, '.', '');
$scores_array[$row['user_name']] = $total; // assign total to the array and i assume that your table has one column name user_name for each user, change accordingly
}
rsort($scores_array);// sort the array in decending order of total scores
foreach ($scores_array as $key=>$value){ // iterate through array
      echo $key.'has scored total score:-'.$value; //print the score along with username
}
?>
```

Note:- Please take the variable names in such a way that they will not produce any ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for this. It is working, One question though, What do you mean by your first point? This is actually my first app using PHP. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Actually `mysql_*` is old library used in php versions below that 5.5. Now this library is totally removed from latest version of php. So your code will not work if you will go for the latest version of php. that's what i am telling

Comment: And please try to update your php versions too. So that your code will work for every latest version of php.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to study more on this deprecated libraries. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. Currently php7 is in market. you have to just upgrade you xampp/wampp/lampp/mamp whatever you are using and it will done.